# Using popmenu within fragment on button

Tags: java, android, xml

trying to display a popupmenu on a button so when clicked it will display the different values. I have converted to a fragment and it is not working as it was when i was using an activity.

Java code

```
public void showPopupCategory(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup2 = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), v);
    //Inflating the Popup using xml file
    popup2.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    popup2.inflate(R.menu.categories);
    popup2.show();
}
```

XML

```
                       <Button
                            android:id="@+id/category"
                            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:onClick="showPopupCategory"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="Category"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Error Message

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method showPopupCategory(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'category'

Answer (score 0):

I see...

Have You Initialised Your Request?

And according to me, you should use a ToolBar for this Task Its more appropriate...
Hope I Helped